# Hw dynamic HTML parser works

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am just making a small online platform. It includes news from different news websites.
I am using JAVA for my website and jsoup parser for parsing HTML.

I am using simple way, First i am downloading HTML pages to local folder and then extracting HTML from it by selectors and filters. eg. doc.select("img")

But just suppose if design of target websites changes, then it will stop working.
and another big problem is different parser for different websites.

I want to make a parser something like google news, HTC news feed.

If any one can point me in the right way.

Comment: well the first thing I'ld do...if to check if these web sites offer the info you want to display in other formats (e.g. RSS, JSON,XML); if they offer to you this way...I guess it would be simpler for you to read these information; anyway..also in this case if the data format changes you can have some trouble....but, as far as i know, the RSS way shoul dbethe better and more sure way

Comment: You are right, but some of then not offering JSON,XML or simply no direct calls.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Another point is most of them not offering RSS feed for Public use, only for personal use.
Another point is it is a project and i want to learn more and more